# Scrapy Unable to scrape API

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl API using scrapy form this [link](https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx)

The thing is the API request I was trying to get solves my all issues but I am not able to load the response in json form and I cannot proceed further.

Though code seems long but the code is only long due to header and cookies please suggest me how I can improve and  find solution

Here is my scrapy code I did

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from liveshare.items import AGMSpiderItems


class SubIndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "subindexes"

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            'authority': 'merolagani.com',
            'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ne;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            # 'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=bbjd1loebaad4ha2qwwxdcfp; _ga=GA1.2.810096005.1667463342; _gid=GA1.2.1263273763.1673850832; _gat=1; __atuvc=4%7C3; __atuvs=63c4efd0a14c6c9b003',
            'pragma': 'no-cache',
            'referer': 'https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
        params = {
            'type': 'market_summary',
        }

        cookies = {
            'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'bbjd1loebaad4ha2qwwxdcfp',
            '_ga': 'GA1.2.810096005.1667463342',
            '_gid': 'GA1.2.1263273763.1673850832',
            '_gat': '1',
            '__atuvc': '4%7C3',
            '__atuvs': '63c4efd0a14c6c9b003',
        }
        api_url = f'https://merolagani.com/handlers/webrequesthandler.ashx{urlencode(params)}'
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=api_url,
            method='GET',
            headers=headers,
            cookies=cookies,
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.headers)
        print(response.body)
        json_response = json.loads(response.body)
        print(json_response)
```

But I am getting JSON decode error I can't figure out the issue.

error traceback

```
  File "C:\Users\Navar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
```

Comment: Please post the error (and full traceback) you get.

Comment: added error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the code - that I simplified - and I got no errors, the JSON data is returned successfully.

Code:

```
url_api = "https://merolagani.com/handlers/webrequesthandler.ashx?type=market_summary"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "Referer": "https://merolagani.com"
}

page = requests.get(url_api, headers=headers)
js_data = json.loads(page.text)
print(js_data)
```

Check the JSON result [here at anotepad.com](https://anotepad.com/notes/cxp83jmr)

Probably the error is in the response of your code - i.e. the response is NOT a JSON object.